# Why string formatting not work in UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, storyboard, xcode6

How set all hyphens on same vertical position?
I use next code:

```
subText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3d%% - %@",subPercent,subfactor];
NSLog(@"%@",subText);
[label setText:subText];
```

But it's look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/amei7.png

Labels created in storyboard and have left text alignment.
App work on iOS 7+

**Upd.**

It's look mad, but work.

```
if (subPercent == 100) {
    subText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%% - %@",subPercent,subfactor];
} else if (subPercent > 9) {
    subText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %d%% - %@",subPercent,subfactor];
} else {
    subText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"    %d%% - %@",subPercent,subfactor];
}
```

Must be better solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, `stringWithFormat` does not adhere religiously to the IEEE printf spec.

Comment: I have never understood why the first comparison is the _most rare_ case (1/100), it is evaluated pointlessly in 99% of cases in runtime...

Comment: @holex - In general, people get the "oddest" case out of the way first.  This is not usually a problem unless you're into premature optimization.

Comment: @HotLicks, everybody says this then the result is a damn slow application. it just says someone is lack of mathematical, and nothing about any optimalisation... that'd start somewhere else, but I'm not going to jump into such debate. ;)

Comment: @holex - In my 40+ years of programming experience, far more projects have failed due to bugs than due to poor performance.  Writing code so that you understand it trumps making it fast.

Comment: @HotLicks, in the last 40 years the things have changed a lot. I developed programs in assembly, 25 years ago but I highly doubt the developes nowadays even know what that is. :) in my experience the bad stuctures causes the bugs, whoch caused pretty much by lack of knowledge of  maths... like this example is the OP, :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your numbers do not line up is that digits and spaces are different widths. However in many fonts, both fixed-width and proportional, all the digits are the same width and Unicode has a "figure space" character U+2007 which is a digit-width space. Unfortunately `printf` comes from pre-Unicode days and does not know about the figure space.

However `NSNumberFormatter` is fully Unicode and localisation aware. To format an integer value between 0 and 100 as an `NSString` of 3 equal width characters you first define your formatter:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
formatter.formatWidth = 3;
formatter.paddingCharacter = @"\u2007"; // figure (digit) space
```

and then use it to format you numbers:

```
int value = 42; // a value between 0 -> 100
NSString *formatted = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(value)];
```

(note the `@(...)` which converts the `int` to an `NSNumber`).

You can do better than this and have `NSNumberFormatter` format a floating point number between `0` and `1` as a percentage complete with the appropriate symbol for percent in the current locale. To do this set up the formatter using:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle;
formatter.formatWidth = 4; // 4 = 3 digits + percent symbol
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0; // so we get a whole number (unless you want x.y%)
formatter.paddingCharacter = @"\u2007"; // figure (digit) space
```

If your value to format is an integer just divide it by `100.0`:

```
int value = 42; // a value between 0 -> 100
NSString *formatted = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(value / 100.0)];
```

Is this a "better solution"? You'll have to decide that and there are plenty of other ways.

HTH

*(For fun: If you would like to stick with `stringWithFormat` consider what the base 10 log of an integer tells you about how many digits it has, and that you can print strings (think padding) with a variable field width - you can avoid your three-way `if` with a bit of math)*

Comment: This solution I was looking for. Thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 1):

How about tabs? Its dead simple.

```
subText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3d%%\t-\t%@",subPercent,subfactor];
```

Comment: Now it's broken on 100% http://i.imgur.com/1iKIpJI.png
If use @"%4d%%\t- %@", will broke on 10-99 numbers too

Comment: You may want to look at your code.
I added 2 tabs. You only have 1.
You also had 3 numbers (3d), now you have 4 (4d)

Comment: Second tab add excess space after hyphen. With %3d it work for all number except 100.

Comment: another option is to make 3 UILabels instead of 1 label. That would guarantee you their position

Comment: I know about it. But must be better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use three different `UILabel`? I think it will be much cleaner then these 'magic' spaces!
You have to imagine if you will have some other words or some other numeric values, you will still use this approach?!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this problem has to do with the width of the space that's used for padding when you're not using a fixed width font. If you use a fixed width font like Courier, your code works ok (but courier is ugly). For a variable width font, I found that you need to use %4d for a 2 digit number and %5d for a one digit number. You can do that like so,

```
subText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%*d%% - %@", 6 - (int)[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",subpercent].length, sub percent, subfactor];
```